# Ansible with winrm only works as root?

Tags: ansible, root, winrm, credssp

I am using ansible 2.9.6, installed with pip, using python 3.7.3 on a debian buster server and I am trying to manage some of our windows 2016 servers with that ; I am already using powershell remoting without problem from other windows servers.

The strange thing is that I can only connect to the windows servers when the command is started as root on the buster server.

For the windows part I am using this in the ansible.cfg :

```
[windows:vars]
ansible_become=false
ansible_user=Administrateur
ansible_password=somepassword
ansible_port=5985
ansible_connection=winrm
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation=ignore
ansible_winrm_transport=credssp
ansible_become_method=runas
```

The results of running a simple win_ping check are :

- As root :

```
sudo ansible -m win_ping srv-prp-tb01c -vvvvvv
ansible 2.9.6
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.7.3 (default, Dec 20 2019, 18:57:59) [GCC 8.3.0]
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
setting up inventory plugins
host_list declined parsing /etc/ansible/hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method
script declined parsing /etc/ansible/hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method
auto declined parsing /etc/ansible/hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method
Parsed /etc/ansible/hosts inventory source with ini plugin
Loading callback plugin minimal of type stdout, v2.0 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/minimal.py
META: ran handlers
Using module file /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ansible/modules/windows/win_ping.ps1
Pipelining is enabled.
<srv-prp-tb01c> ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER: Administrateur on PORT 5985 TO srv-prp-tb01c
<srv-prp-tb01c> WINRM CONNECT: transport=credssp endpoint=http://srv-prp-tb01c:5985/wsman
<srv-prp-tb01c> WINRM OPEN SHELL: 067774F1-8E9A-4366-A5B1-C9A47A2D665F
EXEC (via pipeline wrapper)
<srv-prp-tb01c> WINRM EXEC 'PowerShell' ['-NoProfile', '-NonInteractive', '-ExecutionPolicy', 'Unrestricted', '-EncodedCommand', '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']
<srv-prp-tb01c> WINRM RESULT '<Response code 0, out "{"changed":false,"in", err "#< CLIXML\r\n<Objs Ver">'
<srv-prp-tb01c> WINRM STDOUT {"changed":false,"invocation":{"module_args":{"data":"pong"}},"ping":"pong"}

<srv-prp-tb01c> WINRM STDERR #< CLIXML
<Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04"><Obj S="progress" RefId="0"><TN RefId="0"><T>System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject</T><T>System.Object</T></TN><MS><I64 N="SourceId">1</I64><PR N="Record"><AV>Préparation des modules à la première utilisation.</AV><AI>0</AI><Nil /><PI>-1</PI><PC>-1</PC><T>Completed</T><SR>-1</SR><SD> </SD></PR></MS></Obj></Objs>
<srv-prp-tb01c> WINRM CLOSE SHELL: 067774F1-8E9A-4366-A5B1-C9A47A2D665F
srv-prp-tb01c | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "data": "pong"
        }
    },
    "ping": "pong"
}
META: ran handlers
META: ran handlers
```

- As a normal user :

```
ansible -m win_ping srv-prp-tb01c -vvvvvv
ansible 2.9.6
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/fluxvision/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.7.3 (default, Dec 20 2019, 18:57:59) [GCC 8.3.0]
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
setting up inventory plugins
host_list declined parsing /etc/ansible/hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method
script declined parsing /etc/ansible/hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method
auto declined parsing /etc/ansible/hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method
Parsed /etc/ansible/hosts inventory source with ini plugin
Loading callback plugin minimal of type stdout, v2.0 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/minimal.py
META: ran handlers
Using module file /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ansible/modules/windows/win_ping.ps1
Pipelining is enabled.
<srv-prp-tb01c> ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER: Administrateur on PORT 5985 TO srv-prp-tb01c
<srv-prp-tb01c> WINRM CONNECT: transport=credssp endpoint=http://srv-prp-tb01c:5985/wsman
<srv-prp-tb01c> WINRM CONNECTION ERROR: Server did not response with a CredSSP token after step Step 1. TLS Handshake - actual 'Negotiate, Kerberos, CredSSP'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/connection/winrm.py", line 413, in _winrm_connect
    self.shell_id = protocol.open_shell(codepage=65001)  # UTF-8
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/winrm/protocol.py", line 166, in open_shell
    res = self.send_message(xmltodict.unparse(req))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/winrm/protocol.py", line 243, in send_message
    resp = self.transport.send_message(message)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/winrm/transport.py", line 310, in send_message
    self.build_session()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/winrm/transport.py", line 293, in build_session
    self.setup_encryption()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/winrm/transport.py", line 299, in setup_encryption
    self._send_message_request(prepared_request, '')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/winrm/transport.py", line 328, in _send_message_request
    response = self.session.send(prepared_request, timeout=self.read_timeout_sec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 653, in send
    r = dispatch_hook('response', hooks, r, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/hooks.py", line 31, in dispatch_hook
    _hook_data = hook(hook_data, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/requests_credssp/credssp.py", line 448, in response_hook
    response = self.handle_401(response, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/requests_credssp/credssp.py", line 484, in handle_401
    step_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/requests_credssp/credssp.py", line 517, in _get_credssp_token
    raise AuthenticationException(error_msg)
requests_credssp.exceptions.AuthenticationException: Server did not response with a CredSSP token after step Step 1. TLS Handshake - actual 'Negotiate, Kerberos, CredSSP'
srv-prp-tb01c | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "credssp: Server did not response with a CredSSP token after step Step 1. TLS Handshake - actual 'Negotiate, Kerberos, CredSSP'",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

I am a bit at a loss here. Is this the expected behaviour?

Thanks for your help,

Nicolas

Answer (score 1):

For the record, this has nothing to do with root/non-root.

The normal user environment has proxy definitions. The root account does not have them. After removing the definition, all works fine :

```
ansible@srv-prod-lnx01:~$ ansible -m win_ping srv-prp-tb01c
srv-prp-tb01c | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "credssp: Server did not response with a CredSSP token after step Step 1. TLS Handshake - actual 'Negotiate, Kerberos, CredSSP'",
    "unreachable": true
}

ansible@srv-prod-lnx01:~$ unset HTTP_PROXY

ansible@srv-prod-lnx01:~$ ansible -m win_ping srv-prp-tb01c
srv-prp-tb01c | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
```

For more details:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winrm/proxy-servers-and-winrm#configuring-a-proxy-server-for-winrm-20

Sorry for the noise.

Nicolas